# we have Android Application Size more than max Size?

Tags: android, google-play, apk

What should we do if the size of our Android application is more than max size? Currently the acceptable size for Android applications (i.e. `<App>.apk`) on the Android market is 50 MB.

If our `<Application>.apk` size is more than 50 MB then what's the alternative to follow on?

Comment: I want to know the Uploading case of our Android Application if there Size is greater than the max acceptable size of Android Market.

Comment: I think it's obvious that you won't be able to upload the app if the size is above the max limit... Have you tried optimizing your images and sounds using optimizers?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try removing the resources from the project and changing the app so that the resources will be downloaded upon first app opening to the SD card...
It will take some time to develop the changes, but I don't think you really have a choice...
Note that Samsung devices have an even smaller size limit...

Comment: Just for the record (<3 search engine users): Samsungs limit is 30 MB.

Answer (score 1):

The first reason for .apk size growth is resources. The more specialized application gets on each configuration (screen sizes, orientations, densitites etc) the more .apk size grows. Usually .apk still has size much less then 50 mb limits, but even with 20mb users may perceive your application as heavy.

Android Market added support for multiple .apk per application. This feature was designed to specifically address the issue of .apk size growth due to many different configuration. You can read more about it  in [`Multiple APK Support in Android Market`](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/07/multiple-apk-support-in-android-market.html) post from official Android blog. Though this is considered as last resort.

---

If you .apk size is large due to other reasons, then you're most likely doing something wrong. If its some embedded video/audio file (or even files!), consider moving them to web and download when user needs them for the first time. This will save internal memory space which is might be critical to users (especially on older devices).

Comment: I think you're going the wrong way here.  If you have large media files that are required by the app, it's better to have them in the market.  What's the point of a tiny, useless initial download followed by a few hundred megs of video on the first run?  Just do it all up front.  Google announced support for 4G apks is coming (in June...).

Answer (score 0):

I can't image why an application would be more than 50 mb from just the source code alone.  If alot of the size is in design elements(images, etc) or data(database files), you could always have the user download this info when the application is first run.

Comment: Paying the cost up front in the initial download is a better user experience.

Comment: yea... I understand this, but I don't see how that relates to my post. Obviously you try to put as much as you can in the .apk and if you can't fit everything then you could always have the user download the rest the first time the app is run.

Comment: Sure, but that's just a workaround for a problem that Google says will be fixed soon (assuming the apk is going to fit in 4G...).  It's something to get rid of ASAP.

Answer (score -1):

if you are using Android 2.3.3 version then minimum size of the application must be minimum 9MB and maximum size is depend upon the device,the capacity of memory of the device. but if you take it 50 MB then no problem, its disadvantage is only that the AVD takes time to start.i don't know the Android Market place current application size.

Comment: Sounds very weird to me that the minimum size is 9MB... Anyway, it would be a bad idea to upload an app (even if it is possible) that would be supported only from 2.3.3